# Chrome + selenium + python works for headed chrome, does not work for headless run

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

The following code works perfectly well with headed chrome, but fails with a timeout on the last line with headless chrome

```
import time                                                                               
import chromedriver_autoinstaller                                                         
from selenium import webdriver                                                            
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By                                               
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait                                   
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC                          
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options                                     
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()                                                      
                                                                                          
chrome_options = Options()                                                                
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")                                                 
                                                                                          
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)                                         
                                                                                          
driver.get("http://redacted")                                          
                                                                                          
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(                                                   
    EC.presence_of_element_located(                                                       
        (By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'new-book-rect')]")                            
    ))
```

I checked the similar questions, but don't seem to apply. One indicates that you need to use xpath, rather than id, to lookup the element, but I am already doing so.

What is the reason of the failure, and is there a way to investigate what's going on when running headless?

Using the latest version of Chrome, and the driver is autodownloaded.

Comment: It seems it is detecting bot on headless mode. you can reassure with this `print(driver.page_source)` and check in html whether you have the required element?

Comment: @KunduK well spotted, but in reality what is doing is that there's a single sign on, and with headless it does not go through the SSO redirection dance by itself (it does with headed). It's unclear why it would act differently.

Comment: @KunduK Note that I tried with --enable-features=NetworkService, but it does not work. Same result.

Comment: can you try with this option : `--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`

Comment: @KunduK same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Chromium developers recently added a **2nd** headless mode that functions the same way as normal Chrome. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c36)

`--headless=chrome`

In your script, replace `--headless` with `--headless=chrome` to get the improved headless mode, which functions the same as regular Chrome:

```py
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=chrome")
```

Then your code will work as "perfectly" as it did in regular Chrome.

---

**January 2023 UPDATE:**

Starting with Chrome 109, the Chromium team renamed the option to `--headless=new`. See https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/e9c516118e2e1923757ecb13e6d9fff36775d1f4 for details.